# Unable to create view with Temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hope you can help.

I realise that you cannot have Temp tables in a SQL view so what is the best way to convert the query below so that it can be used in a SQL view.

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT 
    a.KeyField, a.AlphaValue AS Compostable 
INTO 
    #DAT
FROM 
    [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].AdmFormData a
WHERE 
    a.FieldName = 'DAT001'

SELECT 
    b.KeyField, b.AlphaValue AS Trial 
INTO 
    #PAS
FROM 
    [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].AdmFormData b
WHERE 
    b.FieldName = 'PAS001'

SELECT 
    c.KeyField AS JobNumber, c.Compostable, d.Trial
FROM 
    #DAT c 
INNER JOIN 
    #PAS d ON c.KeyField = d.KeyField
WHERE 
    c.KeyField = '00170579'

DROP TABLE #DAT
DROP TABLE #PAS
```

Comment: Look up CTE, Common Table Expression.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps we can just join together the two tables, with the same restrictions, and then select the desired columns:

```
SELECT
    c.KeyField AS JobNumber,
    c.Compostable,
    d.Trial
FROM [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].AdmFormData c
INNER JOIN [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].AdmFormData d
    ON c.KeyField = d.KeyField
WHERE
    c.FieldName = 'DAT001' AND
    d.FieldName = 'PAS001' AND
    c.KeyField = '00170579'
```

Comment: Your answer is better. I just answer the question. You solve the problem ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No, you were right to be cautious and try to stick with the original query as closely as possible.  It's possible for a different question that a simple join would not have replaced what the OP had.

Answer (score 3):

use CTE's

```
WITH [DAT] as (
    SELECT a.KeyField, a.AlphaValue AS Compostable 
    FROM [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].AdmFormData a
    WHERE a.FieldName = 'DAT001'
), [PAS] as (
    SELECT b.KeyField, b.AlphaValue AS Trial
    FROM [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].AdmFormData b
    WHERE b.FieldName = 'PAS001'
)
SELECT c.KeyField AS JobNumber, c.Compostable, d.Trial
FROM [DAT] c 
INNER JOIN [PAS] d ON c.KeyField = d.KeyField
WHERE c.KeyField = '00170579'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CTEs

```
create view MyView
as
with DAT as
(
  SELECT a.KeyField, a.AlphaValue AS Compostable
  FROM [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].AdmFormData a
  WHERE a.FieldName = 'DAT001'
)
, PAS as
( 
  SELECT b.KeyField, b.AlphaValue AS Trial
  FROM [SysproCompanyA].[dbo].AdmFormData b
  WHERE b.FieldName = 'PAS001'
)
  SELECT c.KeyField AS JobNumber, c.Compostable, d.Trial
  FROM DAT c INNER JOIN PAS d ON c.KeyField = d.KeyField
  WHERE c.KeyField = '00170579'
```